# python cassandra : concurrency Insertion and json format

Tags: cassandra

I am a new to cassandra, like to use python-driver for cassandra.

1. Does anyone know a better way to insert concurrently?
2. I have a graph model, built with networkX, is there a good way  to store/load graph model ( node and edges are json format) with cassandra.
   How is the performance/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra python driver supports [async queries](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#asynchronous-queries):

> The driver supports asynchronous query execution through execute_async(). Instead of waiting for the query to complete and returning rows directly, this method almost immediately returns a ResponseFuture object. There are two ways of getting the final result from this object.
>
> The first is by calling result() on it. If the query has not yet completed, this will block until it has and then return the result or raise an Exception if an error occurred.
>
> Alternatively, instead of calling result(), you can attach callback and errback functions through the add_callback(), add_errback(), and add_callbacks(), methods.

As for performance of graph operations, you have to be more specific. But I don't see any possible performance problems with graph storage in C* if you use correct DB schema for that.